# react-native init in current folder overwrites package.json

Tags: react-native

have tried initing an app via react-native init in the current folder, but the command overwrites my package.json and App.js files. How can I avoid this? I'm not trying to create a new project, I'm trying to run an existing one.

Comment: Running an existing react-native app that was created with 'create-react-native-app', should be as simple as typing "npm start" in the directory, as per: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html. If the project has been ejected, you'll probably need to run it on the device, as per: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html

Comment: I think I didn't express myself correctly... the app already exists, that was not created with 'create-react-native-app'. I just want to have it run in order to test it.

Comment: If you have the source code of a react-native app, and it was not created with 'create-react-native-app' or it has already been ejected, then you need to run it using Android Studio or XCode and either emulators or physical devices.